# Character by character in UTF8 file

Tags: python, utf-8

Suppose I had a ASCII file (called 'test.txt') like this:

```
A B C D
X Y Z
     ^   EOF, no CR after the 'Z'...
```

In Python, I could read the last byte (the last character) something like this:

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    f.seek(-1, os.SEEK_END)
    ch=f.read(1)
```

I could truncate the last 3 characters like so:

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    f.seek(-3, os.SEEK_END)
    f.truncate()
```

Now suppose I have a second file (called 'test.utf') encoded in UTF-8 with the following single and multi-byte characters:

```
A B C D
Ⓐ Ⓑ Ⓒ Ⓓ
Z Ⓩ
```

I know how to read the entire file (using codecs):

```
>>> f=codecs.open('/tmp/test.utf', 'r', 'utf-8')
>>> L=f.readlines()
>>> L
[u'A B C D\n', u'\u24b6 \u24b7 \u24b8 \u24b9\n', u'Z \u24cf']
```

And I suppose I could use a deque from the collections module to get the last N characters:

```
>>> from collections import deque
>>> with codecs.open(fn,'r+', encoding) as f:
...    last_3=deque(f.read(),3)
>>> last_3
deque([u'Z', u' ', u'\u24cf'], maxlen=3)
```

So question: Is there anyway (that I am missing) where I can logically step backward through a UTF-8 file character by logical character WITHOUT reading the entire file into memory? With ASCII it is easy; just seek one byte closer to the start of the file. But in UTF-8, `Ⓩ` is 3 bytes (`E2 93 8F`) and `Z` is just one byte.

Recall that UTF-8 is variable width -- between 1 and 4 bytes per character. Unless you start at the beginning, I am think there is no way to know what the character boundaries are...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it, but not as individual characters. Treat the file as bytes.

Each UTF-8 character will consist of 1 to 4 bytes. To read the end of the file, read the last 4*n bytes and start looking for character boundaries. The first byte of a UTF-8 character have the top bit pattern of `0` or `11`, all other bytes inbetween will have the pattern `10`. Just search backwards until you count the proper number matching the pattern.

```
with open('test.txt', 'rb') as f:
    f.seek(-4, os.SEEK_END)
    ch=f.read(4)
    for i in range(3, -1, -1):
        pattern = ord(ch[i]) & 0xc0
        if pattern in (0x00, 0x40, 0xc0):
            ch = ch[i:]
            break
```

Comment: In fact, somewhere online you can find Ken Thompson's email where he explained that this is half the motivation behind UTF-8's design: that you can sync from any point in a stream, forward or backward, reading no more than one character. (The other half is that a byte that represents a printable ASCII character can't be part of any other character's representation.)

Comment: … or maybe you can't find it. At least I can't. The best I could find was the [Plan 9 paper on UTF-8](http://plan9.bell-labs.com/sys/doc/utf.pdf) that he co-authored.

Comment: @abarnert: is this what you're looking for? http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/ucs/utf-8-history.txt, about half way down, quotes Ken Thompson: "6) It should be possible to find the start of a character efficiently starting from an arbitrary location in a byte stream."

Comment: @Neil: That might be it. Although it looks much longer than the one I remember, it's more likely a problem with my memory than with your search. Thanks!

Comment: @Mark Ransom: I think you need to test first for a character with no high bit set, then proceed to the loop that counts bytes with high bits for UTF-8 encoding. i.e., before the loop, test `if ch[3] & 0x80: ch=ch[3] else:` your loop `for i in range(3, -1, -1)` ...  As written, this will set ch to a single utf-8 encoded character or several 7 bit characters.  +1 tho

Comment: @drewk, no it won't do several 7 bit characters - the loop will end with the `break` when i=3.

Answer (score 5):

> Unless you start at the beginning, I am think there is no way to know what the character boundaries are...

That's not true. You can find the beginnings in any chunk of UTF-8:

- If the first bit in a given byte is set, it is part of a multi-byte sequence.
- If the second bit is also set, it is the beginning of such a sequence.

So the first bytes in a sequence either start with '0' (single-byte character) or '11' (first of two or more bytes). Subsequent bytes all start with '10'.

Check out this [chart on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description).

So you only have to read a few bytes from the end of the file to figure out where characters start and end.